# Which is best coding standard let inside for loop or outside

Tags: javascript

Can I use let inside for loop or outside. Which is the best coding standard. I do not know which is the best code standard. If anyone knows please tell me.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

(or)

```js
let i: any;
for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: it depends on the use case. do you need `i` later with a value from the loop?

Comment: @NinaScholz: Which is the best code standard?

Comment: it depends on the scenario but is my perspective using let inside the loop if no need to access outside :)

Comment: It depends if you ever want to use it again after the completion of loop follow the 2nd approach if you don't need the index value after the loop then the first approach.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you should always declare the loop variable in the header:

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
```

There are cases when you need the index after the loop, for example, when you're searching for something and `break` the loop once it's found:

```
let index

for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    if (array[index] === 'search string')
        break
```

However, this code has problems:

- `for` without `let` or `const` is an immediate wtf sign for the reader ("something is missing here")
- you still need a condition after the loop to check if it completed normally ("nothing found") or has been "broken", which might be tricky if the argument is dynamic.
- and, as you already noticed, when working with Typescript, the compiler is unable to infer the correct type of `index`

Therefore, if you need the index afterwards, it's better to have a separate variable to copy it to, and keep the index loop-scoped:

```
let found = -1

for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array[index] === 'search string') {
        found = index
        break
    }
}
    
// after the loop

if (found >= 0)
    ...
```

#### Bottom line: always use `for (let...)`

Note that in `for..of` loops it's customary to use `const` instead of `let` to make the loop variable read-only:

```
for (const item of array)...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access `i` later, then define it outside the loop.
If you don't need it, then inside is neater and better.

Example:

```js
let i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  // something
}
console.log(i); // you can acces it

for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
  // something
}
console.log(j); // error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anywhere you want. It's totally depend on the scenerio. Just have to keep in mind that the defined variable is accessible or not? (Please have a look [Var, Let, and Const – What's the Difference?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/))

If you need anything to access outside the scope (loop, function) in your case i.e. `i` later, then define it outside the loop. If you don't need it, then there is no need to define it outside the scope.

Happy coding.